# Jquery live search script spam

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I wrote this script to my live search:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input#search').keypress(function(){
      $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
      var texto = $('input#search').val();

      if(texto.length > 2){
        $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
        $.post("../index.php/buscar/busca2", { "texto" : texto},
        function(data){
            $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
            var html_final = "";
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                html_final = html_final + value.msg;
            });
                $('ul#pacientes_hint').html(html_final);
        }, "json");
      }else{
      $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
      }
   }); 

});
```

It's working ok and all but when I type too fast it spams querys, how can I make it so only one script execution (the last keypress) runs at a time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery ajax live validation / timeout question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319205/jquery-ajax-live-validation-timeout-question)

Comment: Sorry if it's a duplicate, I just didn't know what to search for

Comment: No problem, it can be tricky to find the correct search terms sometimes.

Comment: Rechecking the question you provided, it isn't quite what I was looking for, is there any way to stop jquery to queue functions and just execute the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be best off using Throttle/Debounce by Ben Alman:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to kill the previous AJAX request before its complete. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xhr;//Declare a global variable
   $('input#search').keypress(function(){
      $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
      var texto = $('input#search').val();

      if(texto.length > 2){

        xhr.abort();//Add this line

        $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");

        //store AJAX object in variable
        xhr = $.post("../index.php/buscar/busca2", { "texto" : texto},
        function(data){
            $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
            var html_final = "";
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                html_final = html_final + value.msg;
            });
                $('ul#pacientes_hint').html(html_final);
        }, "json");
      }else{
      $('ul#pacientes_hint').html("");
      }
   }); 

});
```